# Incorrect MIME Type Loaded on Some Computers

Tags: html, asp.net, mime

I'm experiencing an issue with the incorrect MIME type being loaded for my scripts. In development and upon launch, it worked on my computer but when I viewed it on someone else's computer, none of the external files were loaded. 
Viewing in IE and Chrome Inspect Element, I found the following errors:

**In Chrome:**
*Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html*

**In IE:**
*CSS was ignored due to MIME type mismatch*

Here is the head code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>ToolRoom Scheduling</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runOnLoad.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CollapsibleLists.js"></script>
</head>
```

I checked IIS to make sure the MIME type was set text/css for all css extensions. Any leads would be appreciated.

I am using VB.net in VS 2008.

Under the Network Tab in Chrome Inspect Element, it shows that the external css and js files are being called with the *text/html* contentType, which is being initiated by the server.

Comment: What happens if you browse to those external files directly in the browser that they are not loading on? It sounds like a web server error is being served instead of the content.

Comment: It only brings up the reference to the file, in the head (what I posted above), not the data within the file.

Comment: It's also worth noting that I am getting an uncaught syntax error. Unexpected <.  in the Doctype declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out it was a setting within the browser. We reset the settings back to default and it worked. It also worked on Chrome as well, I'm assuming because it is pulling from the same iexplorer file. Thanks for your time on this.